CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is not passed to compiler: why and how to fix?
I pass compiler flags by setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS via command line as:
$ CC=my_llvm/clang CC=my_llvm/clang++ \
  cmake -DCMAKE_AR=my_llvm/llvm-ar -DCMAKE_LD=my_llvm/lld \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=--target=aarch64-linux-android34 -S src_dir -B build_dir

The documentation for CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS says that:

These flags will be passed to all invocations of the compiler.

However, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is not passed to the compiler:
$ grep -r CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS build_dir -w
build_dir/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=--target=aarch64-linux-android34
build_dir/CMakeCache.txt://ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
build_dir/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1

Instead CXX_FLAGS is passed to the compiler:
$ grep -rP 'clang.*CXX_FLAGS' build_dir -w
build_dir/CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/build.make:        my_llvm/clang++ $(CXX_DEFINES) \
  $(CXX_INCLUDES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -MD \
  -MT CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx.cpp.o \
  -MF CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx.cpp.o.d \
  -o CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx.cpp.o -c xxx.cpp

Why isn't CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS passed to the compiler? How to fix?
How to correctly pass compiler flags to the compiler via command line?

I use Cmake version 3.22.1:
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.22.1

My CMakeLists.txt is simple:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project("xxx")

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        xxx.cpp)

ADD_LIBRARY(abc STATIC
        yyy.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        android
        log
        abc)


If you want to check which parameters are actually passed to the compiler, then use VERBOSE=1 option with make. Inspecting generated Makefiles is not so effective.

How do you know they are not passed? Instead CXX_FLAGS is passed to the compiler: So CXX_FLAGS contain CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, all is fine.

Variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is defined only in the CMake context. Makefiles, generated by CMake, has no access to CMake variables. So you won't find any reference to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in those Makefiles. Just tested: content of CMake variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS becomes part of Make variable CXX_FLAGS. This setting is performed in file CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/flags.make.

@KamilCuk I (incorrectly) thought that CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS needs to be (directly) passed to the compiler. The root cause of my issue is passing CXX_FLAGS to make (see my answer).

@Tsyvarev Exactly (see my answer), thanks. TIL.


Why isn't CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS passed to the compiler?

Because I passed CXX_FLAGS to make as:
$ make ... CXX_FLAGS="xxx"

Hence, passing CXX_FLAGS to make cancels CXX_FLAGS generated by cmake.
My false assumptions:

CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is passed to compiler
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is not converted to CXX_FLAGS


How to fix?

Do not pass CXX_FLAGS to make.

How to correctly pass compiler flags to the compiler via command line?

-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= is OK.
